# What is wrong with this code during enumeration

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
import datetime
with open("fine.txt","r") as f, open("fine1.txt","a") as fine1:
    lines = f.read().split("\n")
    for i in range(2):
        var = input("reg : ") # registration number(reg_num)
        enter = input('Time entered camera 1(24hrs)in the format HH:MM:SS:   ')
        ext = input('Time enterd camera 2 (24hrs)in the format HH:MM:SS : ')
        total_time = '%H:%M:%S'
        enter_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(enter, total_time)
        ext_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(ext, total_time)
        if enter_time > ext_time:
            ext_time += datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
        t_diff = ext_time - enter_time
        time = t_diff.total_seconds() / 3600
        speed = 1 / time
        reg = var[0:1].isalpha() and var[2:3].isdigit() and var[4].isspace() and var[5:7].isalpha() and var.isupper()
        if reg == True:
            for i, line in enumerate(lines):
                if var in line:
                    num = int("{}".format(i))
                    var = f.read()
                    name = (var[num])   #the problem
                    print(name)
                    address = (var[num + 0])
                    if speed > 70:
                        print("ovrspeeding", (var[num + 0]))
                        fine1.write(name+address+speed+"\n")
```

The whole code had to inputted, otherwise you will not understand what i am trying to do.

*fine.txt* is a file that has already been made and looks like:

```
reg_num1 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
reg_num2 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
reg_num3 ccccccccccccccccccc
```

this code takes in inputs of the registration number(e.g. AA01 SSS) and 2 time formats (which will later be used to calculate the speed). i want this code to find the line in *fine.txt* that have the registration number i inputted and if that vehicle is overspeeding(speed >70mph)the whole line needs to be appended into the file *fine1.txt*.

the problem is that when i run the code the error massage states that:

```
name = (var[num])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

i dont what this means, so can you help me with this.

Comment: Looks like `var` is an empty string, so even `var[0]` bombs

Comment: BAH so what should i do

Comment: Theres two `var` assignments, is that intentional? (`var = input("reg : ")` and `var = f.read()`)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the second var assignment? You have already called `read` on `f`, so next time around, it comes back empty, making your `var` empty.

Comment: @BAH well if i try to take that line away another error comes up at the last line. 'fine1.write(name+address+speed+"\n")'
'TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly'

Comment: What do you want your `var` to be after that line? If you do `var=f.read()` and then `print var` what do you expect to be printed?

Comment: You have several issues here. `fine1.write(name+address+str(speed)+"\n")`, or use `str.format()`.  However, `name` and `address` appear to be the same thing (`var[num]`)

Comment: @cdarke ur suggestion wrkd thnks